# Why this error always occurs whenever I want to install sass in my project?

Tags: node.js, npm, sass

```
$ npm install node-sass --save-dev
```

> npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EAI_AGAIN: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/node-sass failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
>   npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
>   npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
>
> node-sass@4.14.0 install F:\waptask\jquery\1st practice\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.14.0\win32-x64-72_binding.node

> node-sass@4.14.0 postinstall F:\waptask\jquery\1st practice\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/build.js

Binary found at F:\waptask\jquery\1st practice\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-72\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN 1st-practice@1.0.0 No repository field.

- node-sass@4.14.0
  added 172 packages from 137 contributors and audited 528 packages in 96.598s

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: Provide us more information about your system, what you've tried.

Comment: $ npm run compile:sass
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-01T10_29_44_114Z-debug.log

Comment: i was installed node.js about 1year.. and i was working with scss ,but yesterday this happens to me and i'm not able to figure out what's the meaning of this error .... then i uninstalled node.js and doing the same process but now 'npm install node-sass --save-dev' also does not work i mean its shown an error.. please help

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. Please format your question with ``` quotes. Try to make it more clear and organized so other can try to help you. I also suggest you check out the GitHub links provided in the error. They might provide you some answers.